# Universal Hash Function Implementation for Strings in Java

Tags: java, hash, computer-science, universal-hashing

I have some troubles understanding the implementation of a universal hash function in Java.
The hash function `(ax + b) mod p` should be implemented in base of H_1.
Also this implementation should work for strings.

I recently worked on this:

```java
public class UniversalHashing {
    // the hash function is a linear function (h(x) = (ax + b) mod p)
    // where a and b are chosen randomly
    // p is a prime number

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int p;

    public UniversalHashing(int a, int b, int p) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.p = p;
    }

    public int hash(String string) {
        int hash = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            hash = (hash * a + string.charAt(i)) % p;
        }
        return (hash + b) % p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UniversalHashing h = new UniversalHashing(5, 3, 11);
        System.out.println(h.hash("hello"));
        System.out.println(h.hash("world"));
        System.out.println(h.hash("hello"));
        System.out.println(h.hash("world"));
    }
}
```

Is this implementation correct or am I on the completely wrong path to implement a universal hash function for String.

thanks for helping me out for this
greez

Comment: By the way we have [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for (comparative) reviews.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing#Hashing_strings shows a quite similar approach and code.

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this?

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class UniversalHashing {
    private final BigInteger a,b;
    private final long p = 1000000007;

    public UniversalHashing(long m) {
        a = BigInteger.valueOf((long) (Math.random() * p));
        b = BigInteger.valueOf((long) (Math.random() * (p - 1L)));
    }

    public int hashCode(String string) {
        BigInteger hash = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            hash = hash.add(BigInteger.valueOf(string.charAt(i)).multiply(a.pow(i)));
        }
        return (int) (hash.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(p)).add(b).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(p)).longValue());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UniversalHashing uh = new UniversalHashing(1000000007);
        System.out.println(uh.hashCode("abc"));
        System.out.println(uh.hashCode("abcd"));
        System.out.println(uh.hashCode("abcde"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That builds up a *gigantic* `BigInteger` and then reduces it in the end. That could be avoided, and equivalent math could be done with only `int` and `long` (iteratively keeping track of the current power of `a`)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).